# How to deploy lightning component with change sets

Tags: change-set

Can someone Please help me to deploy the lightning components via changesets, as I am not getting any option to add the lightning component in the outbound changeset, below is the screenshot for the same.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You Can Add the Lightning Component from-
Select the - **Aura Component Bundle**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Lightning components are available in the Lightning Component Bundle in the drop-down list of the changeset.

You can refer to this:-

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=changesets_about_components.htm&type=0

Comment: Hi Sanket, thank you for responding but I don't have this option "
Lightning Component Bundle" available in the changeset, I have attached a screenshot for the same.

Comment: Which edition are you using? can you tell more about your org?

Comment: I was also searching for lighting component bundle but it was there as aura component bundle

Answer (score 2):

I have got the solution, instead of the lightning component bundle, it is Aura component bundle.

Answer (score 0):

It's AURA BUNDLE/COMPONENT under Change-set.
Although, you can try using METAFORCE (Chrome App). I do my deployment with this tool.

Comment: Not sure why this post got a down vote, but it would probably be better received if you include a link and clearly disclose whether or not you are involved in its development.

Comment: Please add any clarifications via **[edit]**. It's not my question, so telling me won't help anyone really. People don't read the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and got the solution.

There is "Aura Component Bundle" in changeset component picklist. You will get the Lightning component there.